# android when I go to API>19 my Interface to Java gives me "TypeError: Android.mthod is not a function

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs

I have my min API as 16 and all works  but debugging is a real pain, so after API 19 we can use the Chrome debugger, but here my interfaces to the Java code give me the error "TypeError: Android.JavaMethod is not a function", I use this with angular for a hybrid App and it works very well, the iOS version works well with the Safari debugger of course the same code needs some touch up to run in Android and I need the debugger to figure it out. What is wrong with this?

The relevant error

```
[INFO:CONSOLE(11594)] "TypeError: Android.JavaMethod is not a function
09-05 15:24:28.103: I/chromium(18021):     at myJavaMethod 
(file:///android_asset/my_angular/MyFile.js:217:18)
09-05 15:24:28.103: I/chromium(18021):     at Object.<anonymous> 
(file:///android_asset/my_angula/MyFile.js:901:67)
...
```

My JS file

```
function myJavaMethod(curData)
{
  return(Android.JavaMethod(curData));   
} // --- end of myJavaMethod ---

... more code and then i call it from the angular controller
$scope.myCopy = myJavaMethod('arg');                
...
```

My java file

```
weby1.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
weby1.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/my_angular_hl/index.html");

// call to interface to android
weby1.addJavascriptInterface(new JavaScriptInterface(this), "Android");

...
public class JavaScriptInterface 
{
         Context mContext;
         JavaScriptInterface(Context c) {
             mContext = c;
         }

         public String JavaMethod(String arg)
         {
              ..stuff
              return str;
         }

         ... more methods
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once again I answer my own question .. been doing  most of my dev stuff with angularJS and just some low level stuff in Android(BT and the like) that is why I didn't bother to up the API level, after digging thru a bit more I found out that for API17 and above you need to annotate every method in the interface, and also add the import. The error msg is completely misleading and sent me to nowhere land

```
import android.webkit.JavascriptInterface;
...   
@JavascriptInterface
public String JavaMethod(String arg)
{
 ...
```